# Ошибка при работе с контурами

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

При запуске этого кода:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('screenshoot10.jpg')
cv2.imshow('input image', image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
cv2.imshow('canny edges', edged)

_, contours = 
cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.imshow('canny edges after contouring', edged)

print(contours)
print('Numbers of contours found=' + str(len(contours)))

cv2.drawContours(image,contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

получаю ошибку

> OpenCV(4.1.1)
> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function
> 'cv::drawContours'

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Контуры реально получены и количество точек ненулевое?

Comment: какие у вас установлены библотеки, связанные с opencv, и какие у них версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации для findContours, метод возвращает (контуры, иерархия), поэтому я думаю, что код должен быть:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

вместо

```
_, contours = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: Угу, поэтому на пустой contours  и выдаётся assert